# PhpMyAdmin not accessible due to Twig Error

Tags: phpmyadmin, twig

PhpMyAdmin generated 500 error - not aware of any updates to Centos 7 - tried to uninstall and reinstall phpMyAdmin but just get :

> Fatal error: Declaration of
>   Twig_Extensions_TokenParser_Trans::parse(Twig_Token $token) must be
>   compatible with
>   Twig\TokenParser\TokenParserInterface::parse(Twig\Token $token) in
>   /usr/share/php/Twig/Extensions/TokenParser/Trans.php on line 86

when I try to access phpMyAdmin,

PHP 7.2  Centos 7 Mysql 8.0

Comment: There is an [issue](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/2886) open about this at github

Comment: Thanks DarkBee - I did try and look but missed it :)